# Misspelling of "rejected" in suggested edit page

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, user-interface, wording

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3617956

[image]

"Rejected" is spelt wrong, and also there is no person shown as rejecting the edit (I rejected the edit to my own question).

Comment: Spelling issue is actually on all rejected edits, not specific to this one. However, missing reviewer name seems to be appearing on other suggested edits.

Comment: @AzizShaikh, yeah the issue is bigger than the spelling mistake.

Comment: [Here's the Physics.SE version](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5S4hZ.jpg) :D

Comment: Did someone -1 me because it's actually spelt right, someone doesn't like me or they thought the edit shouldn't have been rejected?

Comment: fixed the typo, still investigating why the reviewer is not shown.. reviewers are shown on all other recent suggested edit reviews

Comment: @m0sa: if it helps, it was a suggested edit to my own question. I was the first to reject it, and I had already reviewed 20 suggested edits from the review queue.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I would really love to know the reason for the -1. I'd be banned for using the profanities required to explain the potential reasons..

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy it helps exclude the rendering issues, [other cases](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3589966) [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3612135) render correctly, it must have something to do with exceeding your review quota

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy can you recall which steps in the gui you used to reject the suggested edit?

Comment: @m0sa: I got a notification in the inbox asking me to review the suggested edit. I clicked on the link in the notifications, clicked "reject", "invalid edit" then the reject button in the box. This review did _not_ appear in my review history.

Comment: wow, turns out this has been happening since [early](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/228748) on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty reject will be fixed (for new reviews/suggested edits only) as of build rev `2014.1.9.1838` on meta and `2014.1.9.1289` on sites.